# JButton Unwanted Text Size Change

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have JButtons which I set the text on when they are required, on occasion the text changes size on the button, either larger or smaller. I have added examples below.

[image: smaller] [image: larger]

If I roll the mouse over the button the text returns to the set size. 2000 and 2013 are the set size.

The buttons are created and set as below:

```
//create buttons
 Buttons.add( Btn1 = newImageButton(Picture.Button.getImageIcon(), "Btn1", Color.WHITE));
 x = (int)(0.5f + (0) * getScreenWorking().width);
 y = (int)(0.5f + (yBtnStep + yBtnMargin) * getScreenWorking().height);            
 buildConstraintsFF(Btn1, x, y, -1);

  Btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ButtonAction(evt);
     }
  });
  Btn1.setVisible(false);

 Buttons.add( Btn2 = newImageButton(Picture.Button.getImageIcon(), "Btn2", Color.WHITE));
 x = (int)(0.5f + (xBtnStep) * getScreenWorking().width);
 y = (int)(0.5f + (yBtnStep + yBtnMargin) * getScreenWorking().height);            
 buildConstraintsFF(Btn2, x, y, -1);

  Btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ButtonAction(evt);
     }
  });
  Btn2.setVisible(false);


   public JButton newImageButton(ImageIcon ii, String str, Color col) {
      JButton btn = new JButton(ii);
      Dimension dim = new Dimension(ii.getIconWidth(),
      ii.getIconHeight());
      btn.setPreferredSize(dim);
      btn.setMaximumSize(dim);
      btn.setMinimumSize(dim);
      btn.setText(str);
      btn.setForeground(col);
      btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      btn.setFont(new Font("GothamNarrow-Book", Font.BOLD, 24));

      btn.setBorderPainted(false); 
      btn.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
      btn.setFocusPainted(false); 
      btn.setOpaque(false);
      return(btn);
   }

   //Button text set from list and made visible to size of list
   for(int i=0; i < List.size(); i++){
         btn1 = Buttons.get(i);
         setBtnText(List.get(i), i);
         btn1.setVisible(true);
    }

   //set button text
   public void setBtnText(String str, int i){
     JButton btn = autosButtons.get(i);
     String str2 = "<html><center><font size=6>" + str + "</font></center></html>";
     btn.setText(str2);
     btn.setMargin(new Insets(20,0,20,0));
     btn.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
     btn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
     btn.repaint();
   }

   private JButton Btn1;
   private JButton Btn2;
   public ArrayList<JButton> Buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
   private List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Can someone explain to me why the text is changing size as in the pictures?

Is it a text setting issue or a Swing issue?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you.

Comment: Avoid `str2` as muddles the waters, adding a second font size. The alignment settings belong to the button.

Comment: Why are you mixing images and text when there seem to be more images? You set font size differently in multiple places so that is suspect. Also if anything changes in your constraint and alignment math that could compress text space and possible lead to an implicit font-size readjustment.